# Subdomain .htaccess file issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mysite.net
RewriteRule (.*) user/index.php?fullname=%1
```

The above .htaccess file listens for subdomains and forwards requests to a specific file when it finds one.

In the same directory as the RewriteRule there is a directory called 'edit' which I cannot access because of the current .htaccess file. Is there any way I can modify this .htaccess file so that I can enter mysubdomain.mysite.net/edit and not have it redirect me back to user/index.php?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that the request isn't for a file or directory that actually exists:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mysite.net
RewriteRule (.+) user/index.php?fullname=%1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mysite.net
RewriteRule ^$ user/index.php?fullname=%1
```

Comment: This stopped the RewriteRule from working. It now forwards me to the root directory on the site (when trying to access mysubdomain.mydomain.com)

Comment: @jskidd3 Try separating the rules so that one matches the root and the other matches everything else

Answer (score 0):

Just add a RewriteCond that exempts edit/ from the rule, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite.net
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/edit/?
RewriteRule .* user/index.php?fullname=%1
```

The second condition means "if the requested URI does not contain /edit/ or /edit as a substring". Customize the regex to your exact needs :). Also, make sure to check out the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), it has a ton of good info, and nice examples.